# How do to get the square root of list items, round off and append to list

Tags: python, list, typeerror

How do to get the square root of list items, round off and append to list

Code till now:

```
import math
c=50
h=30

value=[]
item=[x for x in input().split(',')]

for d in item:
    value.append(str(int(round(math.sqrt(2*c*d)/h))))

print(value)
```

I get the error   :

```
value.append (float(round(math.sqrt(2*c*d)/h)))
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

please help

Comment: `item=[float(x) for x in input().split(',')]` - when you split a string results are strings too so you have to convert them to floats, you can get more details by googling `strong typing python` or the like

Comment: Using list comprehensive: value = [str(round(math.sqrt(2 * c * float(d)) / h)) for d in input().spilt(',')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your x is a string value, so elements in item are in string datatype and you cant do math operations with string `item=[x for x in input().split(',')]`

float() and int() are the Python standard built-in functions to convert a string into an integer or float value. You call it with a string containing a number as the argument, and it returns the number converted to an actual integer:

you can write line 6 as
`item=[float(x) for x in input().split(',')]`
OR
`item = list(map(float, input().split(',')))`
OR
In your math calculation convert d to float data type
`for d in item:
    value.append(str(int(round(math.sqrt(2*c* float(d))/h))))`

Comment: thank you. i now got to understand where the error came from and how to improve on it.

Comment: my pleasure, If your problem is solved then please accept my answer, if not then please elaborate errors you are facing

Answer (score 1):

You should also convert them to float. Something like this,

In Python3

`item = list(map(float, input().split(',')))`

In Python2

`item = map(float, input().split(','))`